# The user has been deleted/deactivated (caused by GetDialogsRequest)

Tags: python, telethon

I am using the latest version telethon 1.23. when i connected everything is good. But as soon as I start to download contact avatars (using download_profile_photo ) after the third or fifth count, the account number goes to the ban by telegram. The user has been deleted/deactivated (caused by GetDialogsRequest).
Please help!!!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. When a ban occurs, you should email Telegram support to recover the account (unless it was a VoIP number, in which case don't bother).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

you should try to use your own proxy or use [MTPROTO](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/latest/concepts/botapi-vs-mtproto.html) built-in telegram service

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30874277)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not the only one with this error.
After the release of update 1.24 everything worked.